# What are the benefits of vanilla texlive over texlive provided by Ubuntu repository?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) presumes that vanilla texlive is superior and thus deserves to be installed despite the troubles over Ubuntu `apt-get`. What exactly are these benefits?

I'm considering going back to texlive via `apt-get` due to some issues in Rstudio and knitr, but want to fully understand the trade-offs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some benefits (in no particular order) assuming we are speaking of the Ubuntu official repositories are:

1. **More uptodate packages.** As of today, several months after the release of TexLive 2014 ubuntu 14.04 still has TexLive 2013 or PGF 2.10 in the official repos.
2. **More control over the system.** Even if you only need the e.g. `tcolorbox` ctan-package you have to find the ubuntu-package where they put it (assuming it's even packaged, see 3.) and install all of its content, which may be several megabytes of packages you'll never use.
3. **More packages.** Sooner or later you'll stumble into a ctan-package that has not been packaged for Ubuntu. In such cases you need to perform a manual installation or hope for a third party/unofficial repository.
4. **Easier fallback in case something breaks.** Say that the ubuntu packaging occurs while a broken version of a package as been uploaded to CTAN. If you're using ubuntu packages you are stuck with the broken version until the ubuntu-packager fixes its package, while with `tlmgr` you'll get the fixed version as soon as it is uploaded to CTAN and can easily revert to a previous version of a single package.

I forgot my favorite: **simplicity**. Using Ubuntu packages you are basically introducing another layer of complexity over Texlive, since Texlive already is a distribution system that you are forcing into another distribution system (Ubuntu packaging). With more complexity comes less control, less understanding and a higher risk of breakage. Some distros (say ArchLinux) suggest to install vanilla Texlive over their own packages for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Total agreement, having tried both, as long as you resolve the dependency problems for other packages and set the path correctly. One more reason: nearly everyone on this site is using the most current TeXLive system, so you will be able to get better support here.

Comment: So in short, don't buy themed lego boxes, you can only build the thing on the picture on the box.

Comment: Agree and can only add for clarity re simplicity: vanilla texlive does not entail any dependencies hell.

Comment: As the one responsible for tlmgr *and* the Debian/Ubuntu packages: yes, I agree with what is written, but: (1) if you are writing normal documents (2) are not developing, then the Ubuntu packages might be better, because better integrated. I myself would be content with TL2005 packages - and Zi write a lot of tex code! last: dependency hell comes from *not* using the Debian/Ubuntu packages.

Comment: @norbert It might be useful to add an answer giving these reasons for preferring the ubuntu versions. Just so both sides of the story are represented.

Comment: care to elaborate the downvote?