# Possible bug? \setbeamercovered{invisible} vs. transparent within align* environment

Tags: beamer, align

I'm having some troubles typesetting my equations. I want to be able to uncover them one line at a time, while keeping everything that is on the slide transparent until they are uncovered.

Besides the whole "transparent" thing, if I insert "\setbeamercovered{invisible}" into the code it works perfectly. However, if I change this to "\setbeamercovered{transparent}", some weird things start happening... I've linked a PDF of the output for each case on the odd chance that it's a problem with my compiler.

If I replace \onslide<#-> with \uncover<#-> it gives the exact same output in both cases.

[Here is the transparent overlay.](http://www.slideshare.net/kylebryenton/transparent-49003555)

[Here is the invisible overlay.](http://www.slideshare.net/kylebryenton/invisible-49003554)

```
\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\scriptsize

Then taking the second derivative:\\

\begin{align*}
\onslide<2->{\dfrac{d^{2} u}{dv^{2}} &= \dfrac{d}{dv} \left( \dfrac{df}{dv} y \right) + \dfrac{d}{dv} \left( f \dfrac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{dx}{dv} \right)\\ }
\onslide<3->{&= \Big( \dfrac{d^{2}f}{dv^{2}} \Big) y + \dfrac{df}{dv} \left( \dfrac{dy}{dv} \right) + \left( \dfrac{df}{dv} \right) \dfrac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{dx}{dv} + f \left( \dfrac{d}{dv}      \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right) \dfrac{dx}{dv} + f \dfrac{dy}{dx} \left( \dfrac{d}{dv} \dfrac{dx}{dv} \right)\\}
\onslide<4->{&= \dfrac{d^{2} f}{dv^{2}} y + 2 \dfrac{df}{dv} \dfrac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{dx}{dv} + f \dfrac{d^{2} y}{dx^{2}} \left( \dfrac{dx}{dv} \right)^{2} + f \dfrac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{dx}{dv} \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{dx}{dv} \right)\\}
\onslide<5->{&= \dfrac{d^{2} f}{dv^{2}} y + f \left( \dfrac{dx}{dv} \right)^{2} \dfrac{d^{2} y}{dx^{2}} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} \left[ 2 \dfrac{df}{dv} \dfrac{dx}{dv} + f \dfrac{dx}{dv} \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{dx}{dv} \right) \right]\\}
\end{align*}

\onslide<6->{
Assume:\\

\begin{equation*}
v = \int^{x}_{a} \sqrt{\dfrac{r}{p}} dx^{\prime}, \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \dfrac{dv}{dx} = \sqrt{\dfrac{r}{p}}, \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \dfrac{dx}{dv} = \sqrt{\dfrac{p}{r}}
\end{equation*}}\\

\end{frame}
```

Comment: I think it's a problem in your system. It works for me with `transparent`, `invisible`, `\onslide` and  `\uncover`.  Which latex and beamer version do you use? You can find in `*.log` file. I'm using MikTeX on windows and  beamer 2015/01/05 3.36.

Comment: @Ignasi 

I'm using TexMaker on Ubuntu. I think this is what you are refering to:... Document Class: beamer 2012/10/15 development version 3.24 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 24853e6b98cf)

Comment: Then I think you need to update your system. Here, you can find some information http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114623/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200209/1952

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to outdated software

Comment: [[Jack Black](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/188605/jack-black) speaking] This problem happened because you include "&" in the \uncover environment. Move it out of the environment will solve it. I'm sorry but all answers below are wrong. (from [Edit Suggest #170841](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/170841)) @Ignasi