# How to update TeXLive?

Tags: texlive

TL gets new version every summer. I wonder how to update TL: should I delete last-year-version and then install new one as I usually did in the past or there is a better way?

Comment: If you have enough space, first install the new version, test if all your important projects still work and only then delete the old one.

Comment: "Due to changes in the infrastructure, it is not feasible to upgrade from the TL'15 release to TL'16. (Ditto MacTeX.) Please just do a new installation." Source: [Upgrade from TeX Live 2015 to 2016](https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html)

Comment: Which operating system?  On Linux the packaging system does the whole thing for you automatically.

Comment: That said, it's still on the 2015 version.

Comment: @JPi Vanilla TeXlive (which is basically the one included in mactex) has some advantages, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200209/what-are-the-benefits-of-vanilla-texlive-over-texlive-provided-by-ubuntu-reposit

Comment: @JPi: Windows 10

Comment: @JPi: You're using packages for TL? I've stopped to use the Linux distribution based TeXLive packages about five or six years ago and used the net install always since

Comment: I used to be frustrated with the texlive packaging system in Ubuntu and changed to manual installation.  However, it's much improved in the past few years and if you can stomach receiving texlive updates when the Ubuntu distribution updates then that's less hassle.